# Убрать текст на кнопке "Назад" в SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Можно ли как-то убрать текст на кнопке "Назад", не создавая кастомную кнопку (так как анимация при этом выглядит не очень красиво и нельзя вернуться назад свайпом) и не делая конструкцию `.onAppear{}.onDisappear{}` (так как при переходе между View заголовок пропадает раньше, чем хотелось)?

Comment: Не ответ -- но зачем Вы это делаете? Зачем делать приложение заведомо хуже?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TestBackButtonTitle: View {
@State private var hasTitle = true
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink("Go", destination:
            Text("Details")
                .onAppear {
                    self.hasTitle = false
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    self.hasTitle = true
                }
        )
        .navigationBarTitle(self.hasTitle ? "Master" : "") /*В этой строке*/
    }
}}
```

Comment: А без onAppear и onDisappear никак не сделать? Там заголовок пропадает еще до того, как мы полностью перешли на новую вьюху, и это выглядит плохо.